# not responding while sending json object from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

This is not functioning. What might be the error? I wanted to get name and password from clientside in the form of json to servlet.

index.jsp

```
    <script src=”http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js”>
    </script>
    <script type="text/html">
        function callFun(){
            var n = document.getElementById('n1').value;
            var p = document.getElementById('n2').value;
            var myData = {"mydata" :{"name":n,"password":p}};

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/Page',
                data:{jsonData:JSON.stringify(myData)},
                dataType:'json',

                success:function(data){
                    alert(json["resultText"]);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

    <form>
        Name:<input type="text" name="nam" id="n1"><br>
        Password:<input type="password" name="password" id="n2"><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="callFun()" value="submit">
    </form>
```

this is servlet class Page.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    JSONObject newObj = new JSONObject();
    try(){
        String json = request.getParameter("jsonData");
        JSONObject jsonData = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(json);
        String name = (String) jsonData.get("name");
        System.out.println(name));
    }catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `alert(data["resultText"]);`

Also note you are using an old version of Jquery AJAX. Check the [official Jquery AJAX guide](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for current version. In current version you can use **.fail** call to get the error message

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { id : menuId },
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function( msg ) {
  $( "#log" ).html( msg );
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus ); //Dipslay the error here
});
```

Comment: It didn't help. It neither shows any error too.
The way I am using jsonObject is correct?
 String json = request.getParameter("jsonData");
        JSONObject jsonData = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(json);
        String name = (String) jsonData.get("name");

Comment: What Json library do you use?

Comment: I have been using simple-json